ddjvu: Does it really support converting to PDF?
ddjvu (DjVuLibre), 3.5.28:
ddjvu --help

returns
-format=FMT       Select output format: pbm,pgm,ppm,pnm,rle,tiff.

Note that it doesn't mention PDF. But then, why does the folowing command works and converts input DjVu file to output PDF one?
ddjvu -format=pdf -quality=85 input.djvu output.pdf


Why does the following command works and converts input DjVu file to output PDF?
The --help option appears to be incorrect in your version.
The man page explicitly mentions pdf:

-format=fmt
Specify the output file formats. The recognized file formats are pbm, pgm, ppm, pnm, rle, tiff, and pdf.


Followed by:

Format pdf produces a Portable Document Format (PDF) file. Each page in the resulting file is represented by an image at the specified resolution, using the best available lossless compression model.

Source: ddjvu(1): DjVu decoder - Linux man page

Further Reading

ddjvu(1): DjVu decoder - Linux man page


Hello, David. "The --help option appears to be incorrect in your version." The version 3.5.28 seems to be the most recent one. But yes, it seems this is just an outdated help file. man ddjvu returns me the same text as for you: "The recognized file formats are pbm, pgm, ppm, pnm, rle, tiff, and pdf."
